# How to add delay between Lambda function executions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I'm making an esports data polling app that queries info every time a lol match starts.

The app would be similar to [Automate sports data polling with AWS Step Functions | Integration & Automation](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/automate-sports-data-polling-with-aws-step-functions/) but instead of using Sportradar API I use leaguepedia API, which asks to set a delay of 1-2 seconds between queries (see [Help:Leaguepedia API - Leaguepedia | League of Legends Esports Wiki](https://lol.fandom.com/wiki/Help:Leaguepedia_API#Limits)).

There can be several matches getting played at the same time, so they might bother each other. **How can I add this delay?**

If I add a `time.sleep(2)` at the end of the lambda handler, it just waits 2 seconds for them to execute at the same time again. Maybe with a combination of SQS and `time.sleep()`? Would it be killing flies with cannons to use AWS Step Functions for this?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-eventbridge-scheduler.html

Comment: What do you mean by "it just waits 2 seconds for them to execute at the same time again"? What is triggering your Lambda function? Do you have multiple functions executing at the same time? Have you configured **Reserved concurrency** to limit the number of simultaneous executions of the function? Please Edit your Question and add more details so we can understand your application and the specific problem that you are experiencing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.